# Launching multiple GUI programs from crontab

Tags: linux, cron

I want to launch multiple GUI programs from crontab. I have tried the following, but it did not work:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0 && task1

export DISPLAY=:1.0 && task2
```

When I execute above crontab commands, I am getting error as:

```
**No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]**
```

Comment: This question seems to be more suitable for https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You don't need the `export` command. You can pass environment variables directly with the command line: `DISPLAY=:0.0 task1`

Answer (score 1):

1) You need to allow clients to connect from any host using `xhost + <clientmachineName>`

So it will look like:

```
hostmachine$ xhost + <clientmachineName>
```

2) Then connect to the client machine either directly or from any third machine where the VNC is enabled.

If you are using the third machine & not the client machine itself, then you need to enable x11 forwarding, by executing `ssh -X <username@clientmachine>`

3) After that you can open the gui application of the host machine, from the client terminal running on the client machine or the client terminal running on the vnc session of the third machine, for which `export DISPLAY=<thirdmachine>:<sessionid no>` is required.

Comment: That a hint, but not on target: the crontab user may not be the user who has permissions on the X display (for instance, if it is running as root).  The proper fix (rather than opening up the display - OP did not mention multiple client machines) is to fix the permissions problem, perhaps by sudo'ing in the cron task to the proper user.  That is best done by a script rather than trying to do it in a single line.